# cte to get family tree in many to many relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

i have a table named parents and another of parents_rel. its a many to many relationship where each parent has children and the children have children as well. i want to use a cte to get the family tree of a given parent.
here is my dataset:

**Parents**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | bob |
| 2 | rick |
| 3 | ann |
| 4 | charles |
| 5 | carlos |
| 6 | maria |

**Parents_rel**

| Parent_id | Child_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 |

If i want to see the family tree of bob(1), my expected out come is:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | bob |
| 2 | rick |
| 3 | ann |
| 4 | charles |

im using postgres, so examples in postres would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i ended up doing:

```
WITH RECURSIVE n
AS (
  SELECT p.* 
  FROM parents p  
  WHERE p.id  = "bob"
UNION ALL
  SELECT p1.* 
  FROM (SELECT child_id FROM parents_rel pr INNER JOIN n ON pr.parent_id 
   = n.id) a
INNER JOIN parents p1
 ON a.child_id = p1.id
)
SELECT * FROM n;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE AS(
SELECT id ParentId
  FROM Parents Parent
  WHERE Parent.Name = 'bob'
UNION ALL
SELECT Child_id
  FROM Parents_rel
  JOIN CTE ON Parents_rel.Parent_id = CTE.ParentId
)
SELECT ParentId id, name
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN Parents ON Parents.Id = CTE.ParentId
```

[Try it online](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e70dad6f3a32966f453f6e539d335eab)

Comment: Interesting. I would have joined `Parents` in the recurvise member, but you solution is simpler.